# Element created with innerHTML is not responding to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a div which is created using innerHTML using javascript in a function. This div is supposed to be draggable. However it does not seem to work when innerHTML is used?

Is it possible to drag a div element if its created using the innerHTML method?

ah sorry sorry my bad. This is how the dragging is done. I use event listeners to detect mousedown and mouseup.

the shields array is all the elements that contains the class shield.

the elements array in the mouseup listener function is an array of the divs for dragging and dropping.

each element in the elements array is a new draggable

```
function draggable(name, left, top, width, height, optional) {
        this.div = name;
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.optional = optional;
        this.cwidth = width;

        if (optional) {
            this.dleft = left;
            this.dtop = top;
            this.cwidth = 70;
        }
    }

shields[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
                var e = event || evt;
                var div = this.parentNode;
                dragging[div.id] = true;
                offsetX[div.id] = e.clientX - parseInt(div.style.left);
                offsetY[div.id] = e.clientY - parseInt(div.style.top);
                //$("error").innerHTML = div.id + ":" + div.style.left + ":" + offsetX[div.id] + ":" + div.style.top + ":" + offsetY[div.id];
                this.style.cursor = "move";
                div.style.zIndex = 999;
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);

            shields[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function (evt) {
                var e = event || evt;
                var div = this.parentNode;
                dragging[div.id] = false;
                elements[div.id].left = parseInt(div.style.left);
                elements[div.id].top = parseInt(div.style.top);
                this.style.cursor = "pointer";
                div.style.zIndex = 1;
                reposition();


            }, false);
```

An example of the div that is to be dragged is as below

```
<div id="phone" class="draggable">
Phone: <input type="text" id="phone_field" maxlength="8" />
<div class="shield optional">Phone</div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us how you're trying to make it draggable

Comment: Any HTML elements that created with help of `innerHTML` of root (parent) element has no differences with elements created with help of any other valid method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .on method in jQuery
http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

If you are using old versions you can use .live method to add event listeners to dynamic elements
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Please share your code if you need a specific solution for the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind or re-bind the event handler after DOM insertion.
for example in jquery:

```
$(function(){
    var $mydiv = $("<div class='drag'></div>");
    $("body").append($mydiv);

    // drag event
    $mydiv.focus(function(){
        // your drag function
        // or replace focus() with your drag function
    });
});
```